# Very slow JOIN in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

I am trying to join two large tables (t1: 4.5mio and t2: 100mio. rows) and to collect the information in a new table.
It takes ages (>24h).
I am not an expert so I don't know how to read the query plan and what to optimize.

This is my command:

```
CREATE table new as
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.*, t2.publn_nr, t2.publn_nr_original
FROM addresses_googleresponse t1
JOIN patstat2.tls211_pat_publn t2
    ON t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id
```

`t1.appln_id` and `t2.appln_id` are indexed.

query plan:

```
Unique  (cost=2335238007.81..2344507241.10 rows=72699869 width=14874)"
  ->  Sort  (cost=2335238007.81..2335419757.48 rows=72699869 width=14874)"
       Sort Key: t1.location_id, t1.id, t1.unformattedaddress, t1.ts, t1.googleresponse, t1.parsegoogleresponsestatus, t1.numresults, t1.formattedaddress, t1.lat, t1.lng, t1.maintype, t1.types, t1.viewportarea, t1.administrative_area_level_1, t1.administr (...)"
       ->  Hash Join  (cost=121.82..11099071.55 rows=72699869 width=14874)"
          Hash Cond: (t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id)"
          ->  Seq Scan on addresses_googleresponse t1  (cost=0.00..8410623.64 rows=52302064 width=14608)"
          ->  Hash  (cost=118.34..118.34 rows=278 width=270)"
                ->  Foreign Scan on tls211_pat_publn t2  (cost=100.00..118.34 rows=278 width=270)"
```

Answers to questions below:

t1 is not a temporary table, no (I changed the name to avoid confusion). It has an index on appln_id as described. Table definitions:

```
create table addresses_googleresponse (
id int,
unformattedAddress varchar(500),
ts timestamp,
googleResponse text,
parseGoogleResponseStatus text,
numResults integer,
formattedAddress varchar(500),
lat real,
lng real,
mainType varchar(200),
types text,
viewportArea real,
administrative_area_level_1 varchar(200),
administrative_area_level_2 varchar(200),
administrative_area_level_3 varchar(200),
administrative_area_level_4 varchar(200),
administrative_area_level_5 varchar(200),
airport varchar(200),
country varchar(200),
establishment varchar(200),
floor varchar(200),
locality varchar(200),
natural_feature varchar(200),
neighborhood varchar(200),
park varchar(200),
point_of_interest varchar(200),
post_box varchar(200),
postal_code varchar(200),
postal_code_prefix varchar(200),
postal_code_suffix varchar(200),
postal_town varchar(200),
premise varchar(200),
route varchar(200),
street_address varchar(200),
street_number varchar(200),
sublocality varchar(200),
sublocality_level_1 varchar(200),
sublocality_level_2 varchar(200),
sublocality_level_3 varchar(200),
sublocality_level_4 varchar(200),
sublocality_level_5 varchar(200),
subpremise varchar(200),
ward varchar(200),
data_source varchar(2),
location_id int,
appln_id int
);

CREATE TABLE patstat.tls211_pat_publn
(
pat_publn_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
publn_auth character(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
publn_nr character varying(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
publn_nr_original character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::characte varying, 
publn_kind character(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
appln_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
publn_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31'::date,
publn_lg character(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
publn_first_grant smallint DEFAULT (0)::smallint,
publn_claims smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)::smallint,
CONSTRAINT tls211_pat_publn_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pat_publn_id)
)
```

The goal is to add `publn_nr` and `publn_nr_original` to the other columns in t1 based on the `appln_id` both tables share.

Is `update` of `t1.publn_nr`, `t1.publn_nr_original` an option / faster (after adding the columns to t1?

I am trying without `distinct` now, but it is already running for some hours.

Postgresql version 9.6.5.

Comment: The distinct operation could also be hitting you.  Do you need to select distinct?

Comment: `width=14874` looks suspect. ANYWAY: please add table definitions, etc.

Comment: what do you mean with table definitions?

Comment: joop refers to the `create table` statements. The `distinct` is a bit of a code smell the way you are using it (especially not on 72699869 rows). You should take a step back and describe what the **real** problem is you are trying to solve. Maybe there is better way to solve this.Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Hi, several questions - table name "addresses_googleresponse_temp_2" sounds like temporary table. Does this table has some indexes? What version of PostgreSQL you use, could you add your setting of "work_mem"?

Comment: please see edited information above

Comment: Your `addresses_googleresponse` table doesn't look too normalized. It seems full of redundant+related low-cardinality columns (which you later try to fight with the DISTINCT, which probably doesn't help anyway)

Comment: running it without `DISTINCT` for more than 16h. Any ideas? I need all columns of the `addresses_googleresponse` table in the way they are for now.

Answer (score 1):

For a definitive answer, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output is needed.

However, if PostgreSQL's estimates are correct, then your problem is the `DISTINCT`: PostgreSQL has to sort 72699869 rows to remove duplicates, and that is where the time is spent. See the `cost` estimates.

If you can get rid of `DISTINCT`, do so. If not, try to crank up `work_mem` and see if it makes processing somewhat faster.